# How to use select join two table by using right to specify last character of join values in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I want to used select join with **table_A** and **table_B** and join on **table_A.in_no** = **table_B.in_no**, which **In_no** are difference value.

Example: In_no value in Table_A = ISP1501-1

And In_no value in table_B = 1

So I want to join on in_no by compared on last character of In_no in table_A with its exsprestion -1 as on my images But I can't do it.

Does Codeigniter have some solution for this case ?

**In my model**

```
public function select_in_completed(){ 

            $this->db->select('add_val.*, invoice_all.*');
            $this->db->from('add_val');
            $this->db->join('invoice_all','invoice_all.in_no = add_val.in_no'); 
            $this->query = $this->db->get();
            if($this->query->num_rows()>0){
                return $this->query->result();
            }
        }
```

**And In cotroller**

```
public function index() {

        if($this->logged_in ==TRUE){
            if($this->user_type == "editor"){

                $this->load->model('frontend/report_m');
                $this->data['user_id']  =   $this->user_id;
                $this->data['invoice']  =   $this->report_m->select_in_completed();
                $this->data['subview']  =   'invoice/invoice';
                $this->load->view('frontend/report/complet/view_incom',  $this->data);
            }else{
            redirect(base_url('user/login'));
        }
    }else{
            redirect(base_url('user/login'));
        }
    }
```

**And I used View with simple code foreach function to fetch all data**

**And if I correct value of In_no in in both table to the same value it will work**

[image]

So I would like to ask all member in Stackoverflow. it is possible or not?

Thanks for helping us.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with php string function **str_split()**...here i am proving you the exampple i hope it will helps you

```
$sql=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from table1"));
$table1=str_split($sql['in_no'],1);

$sql2=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from table2"));
$table2=str_split($sql2[in_no],1);

//here conditions go
if($table1[9]==$table2[1])
{
//code runs
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand your variable $table[9]

Comment: sorry i forget to give explanation....here from your database field date was isp1501-39 was there right!!!!!......when we will split the last value will be the array[9]

Comment: I select more than 4000rows if I used to compare more it will slow right?

Comment: i doesn't make much difference you are going with array key right!...i hope there will no issues

Answer (score 0):

You'll need condition like this:

```
$this->db->join('invoice_all',"invoice_all.in_no = SUBSTRING_INDEX(add_val.in_no, '-', -1)");
```

assuming `add_val` is your **table_A**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

You might want to keep this value extracted with `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` in additional column (with an index on it) to make the condition easier and queries faster.

Comment: I used 

$this->db->select('add_val.*, invoice_all.*');
  $this->db->from('add_val');
  $this->db->join('invoice_all','SUBSTRING_INDEX(invoice_all.in_no,'-', -1) = add_val.in_no');
  $this->query = $this->db->get();
  if($this->query->num_rows()>0){
   return $this->query->result();
  }
But not work

Comment: Try `$this->db->join('invoice_all',"SUBSTRING_INDEX(invoice_all.in_no,'-', -1) = add_val.in_no");` otherwise you'll get parse error from PHP beacuse you have single quotes in single quotes.

Comment: I got this 

Error Number: 1582

Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'SUBSTRING_INDEX'

SELECT * FROM (`dbfinan_add_val`) JOIN `dbfinan_invoice_all` ON `SUBSTRING_INDEX`(`dbfinan_invoice_all`.`in_no,'-',` -1) = add_val.in_no

Filename: D:\CooTel\wamp\www\Financial_Project\Financial\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: That's strange. You shouldn't be getting this error if you gave exactly three arguments to SUBSTRING_INDEX()

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring

```
SUBSTRING('isp1501-32',8) gives 32

public function select_in_completed(){ 

            $this->db->select('add_val.*, invoice_all.*');
            $this->db->from('add_val');
            $this->db->join('invoice_all','SUBSTRING(invoice_all.in_no,8) = add_val.in_no'); 
            $this->query = $this->db->get();
            if($this->query->num_rows()>0){
                return $this->query->result();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I got errors

ou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '8) = add_val.in_no' at line 3

Comment: Can you post complete sql generating for above .